# Is there a BitcoinAbuse.com archive?

Tags: fraud, fraudproofs

BitcoinAbuse (https://www.bitcoinabuse.com/) was a community-backed project where you could download the entire database in return.
Since it got acquired/merged into https://www.chainabuse.com/ that is no longer the case.

Does anybody have any recent archive with the full database, or do you know about a service that might have been doing snapshots of the .csv file?